# Convert a list of strings to a String in DrRacket

Tags: racket

How do I convert a list of strings to a String in DrRacket?
For example

(list "c" "o" "k" "e") to "coke"

Answer (score 2):

Try `(list->string lst)` if you're using a list of characters.

Check the docs for `list->string` [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-~3estring%29%29)

Otherwise, if you have a list of strings, try a recursive function with `string-append`.

```
(define (lst_to_str lst)
  (cond
   [(empty? lst) ""]
   [else (string-append (first lst) (lst_to_str (rest lst)))]))
```

Comment: Note: string is not a nice recursive structure. So while using `string-append` recursively works, it is very inefficient (O(n^2) where n is the length). Use `(apply string-append lst)` instead. Alternatively, use `string-join` with `""` as the separator for a time complexity of O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a second answer to illustrate a few more abstract ways to achieve this.

Using [`foldr`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) would be the natural way to abstract over the recursive solution provided in the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58576685/8942807).

```
> (foldr string-append "" (list "c" "o" "k" "e"))
"coke"
```

You can also use [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=apply#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) since [`string-append`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-append%29%29) can accept arbitrarily many arguments:

```
> (apply string-append (list "c" "o" "k" "e"))
"coke"
```

If you're using one of the student languages, you can use the handy [`implode`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html#%28def._htdp-beginner._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-beginner..rkt%29._implode%29%29):

```
> (implode (list "c" "o" "k" "e"))
"coke"
```